# PHP strpos not working properly

Tags: php

why isn't this code working?

```
  output = {"Response":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><LeadEntryResponse xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.abc.com\/\"><LeadEntryResult><AFFILIATES_LEAD xmlns=\"\"><STATUS><LEAD_STATUS>REJECTED<\/LEAD_STATUS><REMARK> LEAD ALREADY EXSITS  - <\/REMARK><\/STATUS><\/AFFILIATES_LEAD><\/LeadEntryResult><\/LeadEntryResponse><\/soap:Body><\/soap:Envelope>"}
    key = LEAD ALREADY EXSITS
    //CODE
    if (strpos($output,$key) !== false)
     {

                         echo "success";
      }
```

output and key coming from the database table.

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/cFlURB) showing it working

Comment: Stack Overflow Driven Development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few number of things why this isn't working, missing $'s, missing quotes and semi colon, and JSON not accessed correctly:

```
<?php
$output = '[{"Response":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><LeadEntryResponse xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.abc.com\/\"><LeadEntryResult><AFFILIATES_LEAD xmlns=\"\"><STATUS><LEAD_STATUS>REJECTED<\/LEAD_STATUS><REMARK> LEAD ALREADY EXSITS  - <\/REMARK><\/STATUS><\/AFFILIATES_LEAD><\/LeadEntryResult><\/LeadEntryResponse><\/soap:Body><\/soap:Envelope>"}]';
$output = json_decode($output);
$key = "LEAD ALREADY EXSITS";
//CODE
if (strpos($output[0]->Response,$key) !== false) {
    echo "success";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first reason why it's not working is that variables should have a `$` prefix.

Secondly,

```
key = LEAD ALREADY EXSITS
```

should be

```
$key = "LEAD ALREADY EXSITS";
```